# What is this moulding?

Tags: trim

Contractor removed and threw away a 12' segment and now I don't have the right material!

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to figure out?  Where to get that same molding?

Comment: Where exactly used? casement, baseboard, window, wainscot header (aka chair rail)?

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is what the profile is called, who makes it, and where I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a 4 1/2 inch colonial base trim. I can't tell you exactly the name or number, but if you take a small sample to your supplier, or preferably the same supplier your contractor used, they will have a chart that shows all the millwork profiles. What you have does not look unusual, so with a little footwork you should be able to find it easily.

Answer (score 0):

The profile shows it's a casing for doors and windows. Common colonial profile. Might need a table saw for the center ledge of the profile.